# 1004 application-defined or object-defined error while naming worksheets vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I would like to rename worksheets in an exiting workbook. This is the code i am using:

```
Dim LobArray As Variant
Dim TypeArray As Variant 
Dim g As String  

'Added during Edit of question.
Dim NoLobs As Long, NoTypes As Long
Dim l As Long, t As Long, s As Long
Dim SheetNames(100) As String
Dim SheetCountSpL As Long
Dim TmplSpl As Workbook
Set TmplSpl = ThisWorkbook
'-----------------------------

g = "_"
LobArray = Array("Lob1", "Lob2", "Lob3", "Lob4")
TypeArray = Array("ea", "pa", "inc")
NoLobs = UBound(LobArray) - LBound(LobArray) + 1
NoTypes = UBound(TypeArray) - LBound(TypeArray) + 1
For l = LBound(LobArray) To UBound(LobArray)
        For t = LBound(TypeArray) To UBound(TypeArray)
            SheetNames(l * NoLobs + t) = LobArray(l) & g & TypeArray(t)
            Next t
 Next l
SheetCountSpL = NoTypes * NoLobs
For s = 1 To SheetCountSpL
    TmplSpL.Worksheets(s).Activate
    TmplSpL.Worksheets(s).Name = SheetNames(s - 1)
  Next s
```

When i reduce the elements in the LobArray to 3 it works. Basically, when the macro has to rename more then 9 sheets, i get the error i mentioned in the title.

Comment: What is the `SheetNames` function?

Comment: `Dim SheetNames(100) As String`

Comment: I've added the `Dim` statements for the missing variables - the VBE option for "Require Variable Declaration" makes code easier to debug and highlights variable typos.

Comment: Providing there's 9 worksheets your code now runs and creates three sheet names per "Lob".  So the problem occurs on this line:  `TmplSpL.Worksheets(s).Name = SheetNames(s - 1)` on sheet number 4 when adding another "Lob" which requires 12 worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to create and rename sheets. It creates sheets based on selected cells and renames the new sheets accordingly. If sheets exist it deletes them

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()


Dim MyCell As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Selection

For Each MyCell In MyRange

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'renames the new worksheet
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the error:**

`LobArray` = four elements.
`TypeArray` = three elements.

1. `l = 0`, `NoLobs = 4`, `t = 0` on first loop.

   - First inner loop:
     `0 * 4 + 0 = 0` = `SheetNames(0) = LobArray(0) & TypeArray(0) = "Lob1_ea"`
   - Second inner loop:
     `0 * 4 + 1 = 1` = `SheetNames(1) = .....`
   - Third inner loop:
     `0 * 4 + 2 = 2` = `SheetNames(2) = .....`
   - Fourth inner loop:
     Doesn't occur as `TypeArray` only has 3 elements.
     **SheetNames(3) is left blank as a result**

This code will rename your sheets:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim LobArray As Variant
    Dim TypeArray As Variant
    Dim lobItm As Variant, typeItm As Variant
    Dim g As String, x As Long
    Dim RequiredSheetCount As Long

    g = "_"
    LobArray = Array("Lob1", "Lob2", "Lob3", "Lob4")
    TypeArray = Array("ea", "pa", "inc")

    RequiredSheetCount = (UBound(LobArray) + 1) * (UBound(TypeArray) + 1)

    If Worksheets.Count >= RequiredSheetCount Then
        For Each lobItm In LobArray
            For Each typeItm In TypeArray
                x = x + 1
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x).Name = lobItm & g & typeItm
            Next typeItm
        Next lobItm
    Else
        MsgBox "The workbook needs at least " & RequiredSheetCount & " sheets to work properly."
    End If

End Sub
```